# How to make one question come at a time rather all comming together in AI Playground

Tags: artificial-intelligence

```
Bot.send ("Hi my name is lexi, a quiz bot");
Bot.send ("There will be a quiz of 2 levels containing 5 question each level");
Bot.send ("Question of First level will be from Science, Second level from GK");
Bot.send ("Type start to play");

var i = 0;
var score = 0;

async function respond(inputText){
    var questionList=[
        "What is the largest planet in the solar system?",
        "What is the largest gland in the body?",
        "The concept of gravity was discovered by which famous physicist?",
        "Which planet is also known by the name of red planet?",
        "What is the process by which solids directly turn into gas?",
        "",
        "Which is the largest flower in the world?",
        "Which country announced the ‘Intermediary Guidelines and Digital Media Ethics Code’?",
        "Which bird lays the largest eggs in the world?",
        "Who was the first President of India?",
        "Who is the winner of the US Open 2019 Men's title?",

    ];
    var answerList=[
        "jupiter",
        "liver",
        "isaac newton",
        "mars",
        "sublimation",
        "",
        "rafflesia",
        "india",
        "ostrich",
        "rajendra prasad",
        "rafael nadal",
        ];

        inputText = inputText.toLowerCase();
    if(inputText === 'start'){
        Bot.send(questionList[i]); 
}
else if (inputText == answerList[i]){
        Bot.send ("your answer is correct");
        i = i+1;
        Bot.send(questionList[i]);
        score++;
     }
    else {
        Bot.send ("incorrect answer");
        Bot.send ("the right answer is "+ answerList[i]);
        i=i+1;
        Bot.send (questionList[i]);
    }
    if (i === 5){
        Bot.send ("First level is finished, Welcome to the second level of GK questions");
        i = i + 1;
        Bot.send (questionList [i]);
    }
    
    if (i >= 6 && i < 10){
        Bot.send ("How was the quiz, If u were able to answer all questions very good, otherwise if u are able to not answer all try next time  ");
        Bot.send ("Your score is" +score );
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        if(inputText === 'start'){
        Bot.send(questionList[i]); 
}

    } 
}
```

The above is my code which I wrote on AiPlayground. Here is a link of my code https://theaiplayground.com/jbobst9/bot/3-level-quiz-bot . I wanted all questions to come one by one. But all question come at a same side.

Eg - Q-1) "What is the largest planet in the solar system?",

Then the person should answer the question and then the next question come. But it is not running that way. All the question are coming at once. How to make it the way I want it to run?

Comment: I have one question regarding this. will this function call again when you send question ?

Comment: If yes, then it will always goes into else part when and will send next question and then again call this function and again send next question.

So you have to put one condition that match question so, will not goes into else until user give answer.